# WF4: How does a NativeActivity remember its children?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

So, I'm at a bit of a loss here. I'm creating a WCF Workflow Service in visual studio 2012. If I have a NativeActivity with exposed child activities that I've filled in using the designer.. **how is it supposed to remember what those children were the next time I open the service's XAML file?**

I've created a NativeActivity with one child of type `InvokeAction<String>` (see below). I initialize the child as the object is initialized, and that seems to be fine.

I've created a custom designer for this activity which simply uses a `WorkflowItemPresenter` to show the child activity (see below).

When, in my WF Service, I add an instance of `NativeActivity1`, I see my custom designer, pre-populated with the instance of `InvokeAction` that I initialized it with. I add some child (say, `WriteLine`) to the `InvokeAction` activity and it shows up, everything seems fine.

I save and build, which succeeds. I close and reopen the WF service designer and... the `WriteLine` is gone. I checked the saved XAML for the WF service, and the `WriteLine` activity never made it into the XAML.

My first thought is that this will always happen because the designer calls the constructor for the `NativeActivity`, which initializes it's child to a child-less `InvokeAction<String>`.

I don't understand how I should set it up so this sort of information should be retained when reopening the designer.

What am I doing wrong here?

**NativeActivity1:**

```
public sealed class NativeActivity1 : NativeActivity
{

    public InvokeAction<String> child = new InvokeAction<string>()
    {
        Argument = new InArgument<string>(CSharpValue<String>.FromValue("string literal")),
    };
    public InvokeAction<String> Child { get { return child; } }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.ScheduleActivity(Child);
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddChild(Child);
    }
}
```

**NativeActivity1Designer**

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="ActivityLibrary.VisualStudio.Design.NativeActivity1Designer"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation">
<Grid>
    <sap:WorkflowItemPresenter Item="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Child, Mode=OneWay}"
                               Margin="5"
                               HintText="Drop Activity Here"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have stumbled across the answer.

Apparently it will only try to remember children that have public getters *and* setters. So, even though I don't want anyone to change the instance of `InvokeAction<String>` associated with the child, it needs to be settable or WF4 won't try to remember what it was.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the `CacheMetadata` override method is that your child action be required:

```
protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
{
    if (this.TargetAction == null)
        metadata.AddValidationError("Target action is required.");
}
```

This way the designer will show a visual indicating that your activity has missing data in it. This should make it more formal.